# Cannot fire a mousedown event with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I'm trying to simulate a click event in http://translate.google.com with jquery. For that purpose, I loaded jquery file with this code:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Then I'm trying to simulate a click on an element with a selector, like this:

```
jQuery(".goog-inline-block.goog-flat-menu-button-caption").trigger("mousedown")
```

I also tried this click event instead of mousedown:

```
jQuery(".goog-inline-block.goog-flat-menu-button-caption").trigger("click")
```

None of them gives the effect of manually clicking to the div, namely opening a new div. I attached the ss of desired behaviour.

[image: clicked state]

What can be the cause for jquery not working? Or how can I simulate the effect in any other ways?

Edit: Adding jQuery seems to be successful in the sense that I can use jQuery method to select elements and change contents of them etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - Are you trying to trigger a click on a 3rd party website using jQuery?

Comment: I think @RoryMcCrossan is right, is it an **iframe** you're trying to get?

Comment: Firstly, `click` is the correct thing to trigger.  Secondly, are you writing an extension?

Comment: No, I'm trying it from Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: @Behlül can you add more details about " I'm trying it from chrome developer tools."?

Comment: That page doesn't have jQuery included.  Have you added it manually?

Comment: @user1671639, I opened the developer console of Chrome, I ran the javascript codes posted in the original question and I couldn't get the desired behaviour.

Comment: @Archer first code snippet in the question is for adding jQuery to the page. It in fact adds jQuery, you can make selections using jQuery method and you can change contents of html elements etc but event firing mechanism of jQuery does not work for some reason.

Comment: Sorry - I see that now.  I was being silly asking that :)  I can't do it myself either.  I've tried several elements, and even checked for attached event handlers of several elements, but can't find anything

Comment: This is a start... `$("#gt-sl-gms-menu").show();`

Comment: Yes, it works but only after clicking to ".goog-inline-block.goog-flat-menu-button-caption" manually.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution was creating a MouseEvent and dispatching it to the element, like this:

```
var e1 = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
e1.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
jQuery('#gt-sl-gms')[0].dispatchEvent(e1)
```

It seems jQuery's event mechanism uses a different dispatching system, since it can not trigger the listener function, though I didn't confirm this info.

Comment: this does'nt work in I.E 9!! Any ideas about a cross browser solution?