# jQuery trigger mousedown registered by addEventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I want to simulate fake `mousedown` event by jQuery `trigger(` method, and I register `mousedown` event by native JavaScript method - `addEventListener()`.  And I found it can't be triggered:

```
elem.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    alert('addEventListener');
});
$(elem).on('mousedown', function () {
    alert('on');
});
$(elem).trigger('mousedown');
```

[Sample in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AUPAh/)

I do some tests about it.

1. Register `mousedown` event by **jQuery `on()`**

- Result: works

2. Register `click` event by `addEventListener()`

- Result: works

Is anything wrong here?

P.S. The reason why I used `addEventListener()` is that I want to write a library without jQuery.

Comment: This code works on manual `mousedown` right and doesn't work when you trigger it via code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But I don't really understand. Why is it not working? As I know, jQuery trigger can execute the handler which is attached on the assigned event. But this sample don't. Is it a limitation of jQuery? Or I misunderstand something? Thanks again.

Comment: The answer can easily be found by reading the documentation for [jQuery.trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), *"Any event handlers attached with **.on() or one of its shortcut methods** are triggered"*, nowhere does it say that `trigger()` will trigger native events!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: **http://jsfiddle.net/AUPAh/2/**

Comment: it's a pity that jQuery does not support triggering native event, because we can use `dispatchEvent` to trigger a native event but the actual solution (works across browsers) is not trivial, so it would be better if jQuery solved that cross-browser problem. However you can try writing your own plugin and re-use it.

Comment: @adeneo Thanks for your explanation and document. It's helpful. :)

Comment: Note that even if the trigger works, `onmousedown` is a complicated event with many info (ctrlKey, shiftKey, button, coordinates related properties, ...) which should be passed into the `event` object. So it's not easy to trigger the `onmousedown` in a proper way. Unless try using native javascript with `createEvent()` and `dispatchEvent()` methods.

Comment: @King King Thanks. Yep... I want to use jQuery trigger to solve cross-browser problem.

Answer (score 9):

Try using

```
EventTarget.dispatchEvent
```

[MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent)

Your code will be something like

```
var elem = document.getElementById('square');
elem.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    alert('addEventListener');
});
$(elem).on('mousedown', function () {
    alert('on');
});

elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown'))
```

You might have to use `fireEvent` if you are considering IE.

```
object.fireEvent(bstrEventName, pvarEventObject, pfCancelled)
```

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/ms536423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It would be like

```
if (document.createEvent) {
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
} else {
    element.fireEvent("on" + event.eventType, event);
}
```

Comment: Strangely, it did not worked. This one works - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18631561/566092

Answer (score 5):

Jquery Only triggers the events that created by itself

Even the order is also matters like  : **this Works**

```
$(elem).on('mousedown', function () {
    alert('on');
});
$(elem).trigger('mousedown');
```

But Below code Will **not Work**

```
 $(elem).trigger('mousedown');
 $(elem).on('mousedown', function () {
    alert('on');
});
```

Take A look at This **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mbanandetoro6/hfVe5/1/)**

Comment: But I try to use addEventListener to register click event, and fire it by jQuery trigger(), it works...

Comment: @Sam let me check, give me a demo link if you already done it

Comment: @Sam looks like `trigger()` can just trigger some limited events, such as it can trigger the `onclick` event but can't trigger `onmousedown` event

Comment: @MaulikAnand interesting, it can trigger the event handler registered by assigning not by `addEventListener`.